How to get powershell environment variable value in terraform
Running powershell (7.4.1) and terraform (1.7.5) on Ubuntu (20.04). I have created a powershell profile in which I set some environment variables for terraform to use when executing it.
For example, in 'Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1' I have set.
$env:DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="abcd1234"
gci env:DA_*

And when I run pwsh I can see the value printed to console.
Name                           Value
----                           -----
DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID             abcd1234`

Then I have a terraform file 'providers.tf' (among other tf-files) having content like this.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "${env.DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}"
}

Now, in the powershell console, when I run terraform validate.
I get response:
A managed resource "env" "DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" has not been declared in the root module.

May be simple, but I am not able to find the correct syntax to use when referring to the environment variables set in the powershell profile.
Could someone give me an advice on how to do this correctly.
Thanks.

The normal way to refer to an environment variable in Powershell is $env:varname.

First, you have to declare a variable in Terraform.
variable "DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" {
  type = string
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
}

Then, you can set an environment variable in your shell with the TF_VAR_ prefix. Terraform searches the environment of its own process for environment variables named TF_VAR_ followed by the name of a declared variable.
$env:TF_VAR_DA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="abcd1234"
terraform plan


I was close, but did not have it quite right. I miss understood where that 'TF_VAR_' was supposed to be used. Thanks.

There's no need to declare a variable like that. As long as you define ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID in your PowerShell environment, Terraform will use  it for the provider configuration, refer to the Azure provider documentation.
However, if you want to explicitly set a different variable for setting the subscription ID, what @vrdse suggested is correct.

The tutorial I used instructed on using the 'ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID' but did not event try it since I needed other variables also, and eventually I would need to use that 'TF_VAR' syntax anyway. I didn't want to mix these as I feel it would had left things a bit confusing.
